# The geometric shape of domains of flows

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, flows

Consider a smooth (non-compact) manifold $M$ with a vector field $X$. Then we know that there is a open neighbourhood $U \subseteq M \times \mathbb{R}$ of $M \times \{0\}$ such that on $U$ the flow $\Phi$ of $X$ is defined. The uniquely determined maximal such $U$ can be obtained as the union of all the initial conditions with the maximal time interval on which the particular solution curve is defined, i.e. $U = \bigcup_{p \in M} \{p\} \times I_p$ where $I_p \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is the maximal open interval around $t = 0$ where $\Phi(p, t)$ is an integral curve of $X$ with initial condition $p$.

Now it is fairly easy to see that $U$ has certain properties like: if there is a non-zero $\epsilon$ such that $M \times (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \subseteq U$ then $U = M \times \mathbb{R}$, i.e. if the solutions are defined for a common small time uniformly for all initial conditions then the flow is already complete, a feature which is of course very nice to have. If $M$ is compact, this is of course always fulfilled.

My question is now how one can characterize the possible domains of in-complete flows: is the above condition the only thing which has to fail for $U$ in order to find a vector field $X$ such that its flow has precisely $U$ as domain for the flow? Or are there other conditions on $U$ which makes $U$ a domain of a flow beyond the above necessary "non-uniform width"?

Comment: There are many other obvious properties $U$ has to have: $U$ is open; if $I_p\not=\mathbb R$, then there are other points $q$ for which $I_q$ is a shift of $I_p$, and some of them are arbitrarily close to $p$; if (say) $M=S^2\setminus{N}$, then for $q$ from the southern hemisphere, $I_q$ contains the intersection of the $I_p$ for $p$ from the equator etc. etc. I'm skeptical if this can have a good answer other than in the trivial one-dimensional case; maybe a more specific conjecture would be helpful.

Comment: @Christian Remling. Maybe you are right, an there is no simple characterization. Unfortunately, I do not have a more specific conjecture :( Anyway, thanks for this comment!

Comment: @StefanWaldmann This comment is indirectly related to your question:There is  a paper by C. Chicone and J. Sotomayor in JDE which classify all complete polynomial vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ in term of the nature of singularities at infinity (Poincare compactification). According to their result existence of hyperbolic singularity at the equator implies the vec, field on the plane is not complete.

Comment: @Ali Taghavi Thanks, I will take a look.